# How to add this circularProgressBar View in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to add Circular Progress Bar View which is percentageDoughnut, how can I add to UICollection view, so it can give good animation, it is not allowing swipe gesture which is quite odd but UICollectionView will be the good alternative? Any clue.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.percentageDoughnut = [[MCPercentageDoughnutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 35, 289, 311)];
    self.percentageDoughnut.dataSource              = self;
    self.percentageDoughnut.percentage              = 0.5;
    self.percentageDoughnut.linePercentage          = 0.15;
    self.percentageDoughnut.animationDuration       = 2;
    self.percentageDoughnut.decimalPlaces           = 1;
    self.percentageDoughnut.showTextLabel           = YES;
    self.percentageDoughnut.animatesBegining        = NO;
    self.percentageDoughnut.fillColor               = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.percentageDoughnut.unfillColor             = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultGrayColorForBackground];
    self.percentageDoughnut.textLabel.textColor     = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.percentageDoughnut.textLabel.font          = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
    self.percentageDoughnut.gradientColor1          = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.percentageDoughnut.gradientColor2          = [MCUtil iOS7DefaultGrayColorForBackground];


    [self.view addSubview:self.percentageDoughnut];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToDoMethod)];
    [swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.percentageDoughnut addGestureRecognizer: swipeGesture];
}
- (void)swipeToDoMethod{

    NSLog(@"swiped");
}

- (UIView*)viewForCenterOfPercentageDoughnutView:(MCPercentageDoughnutView *)pecentageDoughnutView
                                  withCenterView:(UIView *)centerView {
    //    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //    UIViewController *progressContentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"progressContent"];
    //    progressContentViewController.view.frame = centerView.bounds;
    //
    //    return progressContentViewController.view;

    // Uncomment to see an image example
    //*
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brazil-shape.png"]];
    imageView.frame = centerView.bounds;
    return imageView;
    //*/
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToDoMethod)];
    [swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer: swipeGesture];
    self.percentageDoughnut.showTextLabel = NO;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:centerView.bounds];
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    NSMutableAttributedString *s = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"GB(59%)"];
    [s addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40] range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
    [s addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] range:NSMakeRange(2, 3)];
    label.attributedText = s;
    return label;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) MCPercentageDoughnutView *percentageDoughnut;
```

UICollection view it can display one view at a time, i am displaying steps in CircularProgressBar.

Comment: Any clue guys will be highly appreciated.